# ICS file - using PHP, want to insert new line characters to break up description into paragraphs

Tags: php, icalendar

I'm creating an ICS file dynamically with PHP which is "mostly" working except for one snag:

In the DESCRIPTION area of the ICS file, I want to concatentate several database fields and separate them into their own paragraphs so when the user opens the calendar entry, they're not all concatentated as one string.

My problem is that if I try and concatenate these fields using the new line characters, the "\n" isn't showing up as part of the DESCRIPTION content. I've opened a valid ICS file that accomplishes this task and the file shows:

DESCRIPTION:1. Click this link to join the Webinar:\n\n   https://www1.site.com/join/444/444444\n\n\n2. Choose one of the following audio options:\n\n

The "\n" is part of the file content. But if I try and generate it, it treats the \n as not content, but the end of the line of the ICS line:

DESCRIPTION:line1

line2

So the ICS can't be read and isn't valid.

I've tried many combinations, but can't seem to get this working. Seems like it should be simple, but isn't. Any ideas?

Comment: So, is it just wanting a literal "\n" (i.e. a backslash followed by an n)? What does your *code* actually look like? How are you concatenating your \n? If it's hardcoded in a string, are you using single or double quotes for the string? (Hint: that makes a difference.) Have you tried escaping the backslash (e.g. using "\\n")? Fundamentally, it's hard for us to help unless you post your relevant code.

Comment: Matt, thanks for responding and fixing my "duh" issue. I wasn't escaping the "\n" with an additional slash. I used " \\n " and, keeping the space in front and back, the content in the DESCRIPTION field of the ICS file is now separated into paragraphs. Without the spaces, the second paragraph was lopped off even though the ics file still showed up in iCalendar. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

The icalendar DESCRIPTION field uses two separate characters, '\' followed by 'n' to represent line breaks. If you're writing a [PHP string literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) with those characters, you can either use a string with single quotes and simply write `\n`, or use double quotes and escape the backslash so that `\n` isn't turned into a newline character. For example:

```
$description = 'This is a description\nwith a newline';
// Or
$description = "This is a description\\nwith a newline";
```

Exactly how you'll end up doing it depends on your source code, which we've not seen.