# str_replace in .ics file not working

Tags: php, icalendar

I've tried a few different methods and can't seem to get any of them working. On my site, I have an area to create an appointment (screenshots below). The appointment description posts to the database correctly. Once the appointment is created, a .ics file is emailed to whomever the appointment is set for. The .ics file has all the lines, but the line breaks aren't going into the Outlook appointment so it's only showing the first line. I've tried using the str_replace as seen below, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**EDIT:** I got the \n going into the .ics file, but Outlook is still not showing anything except for the first line.

[image: screenshot]

## ***Screenshot of Add Appointment modal***

[image: Create Appointment]

## ***Screenshot of Outlook Appointment from .ics file***

[image: Outlook Appointment]

## ***Screenshot of .ics text in Notepad***

[image: .ics Text Output]

## ***Relevant .php code for creating .ics file***

```
$appNote = str_replace("\r\n", "\\n", $_POST['appNote']);
$appNote = htmlspecialchars($appNote, ENT_QUOTES);

$ical_content = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE"
.$adtimezone."
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:".$createdDate."
DESCRIPTION:".$appNote."
DTEND;TZID=\"".$appTimeZone."\":".$endDateTime."
DTSTAMP:".$createdDate."
DTSTART;TZID=\"".$appTimeZone."\":".$startDateTime."
LAST-MODIFIED:".$createdDate."
LOCATION:".$appLocation."
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:".$appSubject." - ".$clientusername."
".$reminderinfo;


$ical_content = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE"
.$adtimezone."
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:".$createdDate."
DESCRIPTION:".$appNote."
DTEND;TZID=\"".$appTimeZone."\":".$endDateTime."
DTSTAMP:".$createdDate."
DTSTART;TZID=\"".$appTimeZone."\":".$startDateTime."
LAST-MODIFIED:".$createdDate."
LOCATION:".$appLocation."
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:".$appSubject." - ".$clientusername."
".$reminderinfo;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ICS file - using PHP, want to insert new line characters to break up description into paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336179/ics-file-using-php-want-to-insert-new-line-characters-to-break-up-description)

Comment: I edited the original post. I got the \n to go into the .ics file, but it's still not loading into Outlook

Comment: Your screenshot from notepad does not show any `\n` character combination in that place.

Comment: Not from the original post, but if you look at the screenshot immediately underneath my "Edit" you can see the `\n` in the line. Still not working in the description of the Outlook appt

Comment: Does wrapping the description content in " change anything? Can you _export_ such an event from Outlook and check what exact format it creates in such a case?

Comment: I created an event in Outlook and saved it, then viewed it in Notepad. It places the \n between the lines just as my file has. I tried surrounding the description content in " and it's not helping.

Comment: When I create one in Outlook, I notice that it uses `0d 0a` line breaks between the individual properties (like what is marked with `##` here: `CREATED:20180419T075104Z##DESCRIPTION:Test\nFoobar\nBlubb\n##DTEND;` etc.) Depending on how you saved (or transferred via FTP) your file, the line breaks inside your given text in the `$ical_content` variable however might just use `0d` or `0a` only. I’d try to make sure that those are `0d 0a`. (If they were, then Notepad should have recognized them to begin with.)

Comment: I also noticed that when I export from Outlook, it has the breaks between properties, but the ics generated from php is not separated. What do I need to do to make sure that it's done that way?

Comment: As I just said, check how you saved/transferred your PHP script. You are defining most of this text in a variable there, so whether your script file itself is saved using \r\n or \n as line break sequence, also directly influences what this variable eventually contains. It might make most sense if you don’t rely on “implicit” line breaks from the code structure here to begin with, but explicitly use \r\n inside your string. (If you don’t want to have to write it all in one line, then go `$foo = "bar\r\n" . [line break] "next line\r\n"` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the iCalendar specification, you need a carriage return and linefeed after each line, i.e. "\r\n". You are also missing the UID item, which is required, and you need to wrap lines that are longer than 75 characters.

You may want to consider using a PHP library that does all of this for you. You should also check your resulting iCalendar file with a validator like the one at [icalendar.org](http://icalendar.org) to make sure it is a valid file, which increases the likelihood the file will be imported successfully.